# Use containers for templates in vuejs using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

TL;DR

For my Vuejs projects I always separate the dashboard and content. I create a directory called containers to render my dashboard from there, with the possibility of having multiple dashboards. Using normal javascript the router works perfectly.

link working in codesandbox: [Js - Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-containers-dashboard-js-bpnmx?file=/src/main.js)

The problem is when I migrate to typescript, the router fails to open links, shows errors, duplicates template, it doesn't work to go back or sometimes it doesn't push to the other view.

I have posted a [repository on github](https://github.com/braian125/vuejs-containers-dashboard) with two branches: master (working with javascript) and typescript-way (router not working). If I manually enter in the address bar or when reloading (f5) each route works fine, but when clicking on the links it shows errors

Next I want to show how it works well using javascript:

```
src/
  - components/
  - containers/
    - dashboard/
      - layout/
        - Header.vue
        - Sidebar.vue
          ...
      - Dashboard.vue
  - router/
  - store/
  - views/
  - App.vue
  - main.js
```

//router.js

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: '',
      redirect: 'home',
      component: () => import('@/containers/dashboard/Dashboard'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'home',
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ './views/Home')
        },
        {
          path: '/about',
          name: 'about',
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About')
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/Login')
    }
 ]
```

//App.vue

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

//containers/dashboard/Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page-container">
            <sidebar/>
            <div id="main-container">
                <header-app @sidebarToggle="sidebarToggle" @logout="logout" />
                <div id="page-content">
                    <router-view/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
.....
</script>
```

for typescript I use the same concept with the code adapted for vue and typescript

Comment: "but when clicking on the links it shows errors" what are the errors being shown?

Comment: Hi @Evan I am using <router-link to = ""> I think it does a page push, the first time I click it works, the following clicks change the url but the view does not change

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in following a tutorial that recommended importing Vue and Component from vue-property-decorator

```
import {Vue, Component} from "vue-property-decorator"
```

The above causes the router to not work correctly, when reading the official documentation and using:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
```

it works perfectly

thanks to those who read